# Dismiss keyboard when user swipes inside scrollview

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I have my label and textfields inside a scrollview.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];
tapGesture.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[scrollBill addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

I can dismiss the keyboard by tapping on the scrollview. But how do I dismiss the keyboard when the user either swipes or taps on the scrollview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dismissal on tap, you use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`, as you already have.

For dismissal on drag you simply set the `keyboardDismissalMode` of your `UIScrollView` to `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag`.

Sample code:

```
scrollBill.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

Answer (score 1):

used this inside a hideKeyboard method

```
[self.view endEditing:YES];
```

or

```
[scrollBill endEditing:YES];
```

It works properly.

Answer (score 1):

in scrollBill init method, set Delegate:

```
scrollBill.delegate = self;
```

implement scrollView delegate, scroll to hideKeyboard

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self resignFirstResponder];
}
```